# How does purchasing provisions or catering semantically relate to facilitating phagocytosis?

Tags: medicine

Why did physician choose *obsōnāre* to create [opsonin](https://www-oed-com/view/Entry/132044#eid33208349)?  Rendering pathogens more susceptible to phagocytosis doesn't feel connected to purchasing provisions or catering.

> **Etymology:** < classical Latin *obsōnāre*, *opsōnāre** to purchase provisions, cater* (see [opsonation n.](https://www-oed-com/view/Entry/129935#eid33673818)) + [-in suffix1](https://www-oed-com/view/Entry/92976#eid742356). Compare [opsonic adj.](https://www-oed-com/view/Entry/132043#eid33208233)  (first attested in the same source: see quot. [1903](https://www-oed-com/view/Entry/132044#eid33208406)). Compare slightly later French *opsonine* (dated 1904 in Robert *Dict. alphabétique et analogique* (1986)).... [(Show Less)](https://www-oed-com/view/Entry/132044#)
>
> *Medicine* and *Bacteriology*.
>
> A substance (often an antibody) in blood serum which combines with bacteria or other foreign cells and renders them more susceptible to phagocytosis.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word *opsonin* actually comes from the Greek ὀψωνεῖν (opsōneîn), which, in turn, is the verb associated with ὄψον (opson), which is often translated as *relish*. It was an integral part of the Greek meal and often consisted of fish, but not necessarily so:

> Those who could afford nothing better had bread in some shape or other
>   as their food and their only staff of life, but all who had the means
>   added something to eat with it, and this naturally took the form of
>   something cooked, ὄψον properly so called: the term, however, became
>   so far conventional that it was possible to use it for any dainty
>   which helped to make the bread more palatable (and for which, in
>   default of anything else, λιμὸς is proverbially used, Xen. Cyr. 1.5,
>   12); ([A Dictionary of Greek and Roman Antiquities](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0063%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DO%3Aentry%20group%3D1%3Aentry%3Dopson-cn). William Smith,
>   et al.)

The verb [ὀψωνεῖν](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=o%29ywnei%3Dn&la=greek#lexicon) means *to buy fish or to buy victuals in general*. However, it has been take in a broader sense, in the naming of opsonin, to signify *to prepare for eating*. The relation is clearly expressed in a textbook of immunology:

> **Opsonin**. Antibody that attaches to a cellular or particulate antigen and
>   "prepares" it for phagocytosis (James T. Barrett, [*Basic immunology
>   and its medical application*](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Basic_immunology_and_its_medical_applica.html?id=xgBrAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y), pg. 292)

In other words, opsonin prepares for the eating of cells (phagocytosis: from φαγεῖν (phagein), *to eat*, and κύτος, *cell*). This idea was colorfully expressed by [Thomas S. Kickler](https://ashpublications.org/blood/article/131/1/10/107682/The-delectability-of-platelets-to-a-phagocyte) who said that opsonin "causes the phagocyte to 'relish' the marked cell".